# Processing charge current error messages with HashMap<>

Tags: performance, hash-map, android, error-handling, kotlin

I have certain error states that I am displaying in my Android TextView but only one message is displayed at a time and if all values are set to 0, no message is displayed. So, I check all the values with if-else and set the associated switch in the `chargeCurrentMap`. I then clear the error message if all values in the map are 0.

My concern is that my Kotlin code is too long and clunky. How can I improve it?

```
private var chargeCurrentMap = HashMap<String?, Int?>()
private lateinit var chargeCurrentErrorMessage: String

private fun processChargeModes(data: ByteArray, increment: Int = 0) {
        deviceData.restMode = data[28].toInt()
        if (deviceData.restMode == 1) {
            chargeCurrentErrorMessage = "Battery full, charger is off"
            chargeCurrentMap["rest"] = 1
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "Off"
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            chargeCurrentMap["rest"] = 0
        }
        deviceData.misbalancedMode = data[29].toInt()
        if (deviceData.misbalancedMode == 1) {
            chargeCurrentErrorMessage = "Charging is paused, battery is resolving a minor issue"
            chargeCurrentMap["misbalanced"] = 1
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "Off"
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            chargeCurrentMap["misbalanced"] = 0
        }
        deviceData.leftChargedMode = data[30].toInt()
        if (deviceData.leftChargedMode == 1) {
            chargeCurrentErrorMessage = "Charger is off, pack left fully charged for too long. Drive golf cart until battery reaches less than 90%"
            chargeCurrentMap["leftCharged"] = 1
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "Off"
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            chargeCurrentMap["leftCharged"] = 0
        }
        deviceData.highVoltageMode = data[31].toInt()
        if (deviceData.highVoltageMode == 1) {
            chargeCurrentErrorMessage = "Charger is off, battery voltage is too high"
            chargeCurrentMap["highVoltage"] = 1
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "Off"
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            chargeCurrentMap["highVoltage"] = 0
        }
        deviceData.highTempMode = data[32].toInt()
        if (deviceData.highTempMode == 1) {
            chargeCurrentErrorMessage = "Charger is off, battery temperature is too high"
            chargeCurrentMap["highTemp"] = 1
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "Off"
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            chargeCurrentMap["highTemp"] = 0
        }
        deviceData.lowTempMode = data[33 + increment].toInt()
        if (deviceData.lowTempMode == 1) {
            chargeCurrentErrorMessage = "Charger is off, battery temperature is too low"
            chargeCurrentMap["lowTemp"] = 1
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "Off"
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            chargeCurrentMap["lowTemp"] = 0
        }

        if (increment == 0 && !chargeCurrentMap.containsValue(1)) {
            chargeCurrentErrorMessage = ""
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "On"
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(currentTextColor)
            binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.GONE
        } else if (increment == 1) {
            deviceData.hotChargerMode = data[33].toInt()

            if (deviceData.hotChargerMode == 1) {
                chargeCurrentErrorMessage = "Charger resting for a moment to let the battery cool"
                chargeCurrentMap["hotCharger"] = 1
                binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "Off"
                binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED)
                binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                chargeCurrentMap["hotCharger"] = 0
            }

            if (!chargeCurrentMap.containsValue(1)) {
                chargeCurrentErrorMessage = ""
                binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "On"
                binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(currentTextColor)
                binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between `deviceData` and `DeviceData`? The two different cases confuses me.

Comment: Can the `increment` value be anything else than 0 or 1 ? And the same with `DeviceData.misbalancedMode` and the other values for the if-checks you are checking?

Comment: @SimonForsberg Yeah, sorry. All those Uppercase "D" characters are supposed to be lowercase. I will edit that real quick. Also, increment does have to stay either 1 or 0. There are certain error states that only occur on certain devices so the increment is just for me to differentiate between two possible cases of device types.

Comment: And the `deviceData.leftChargedMode` etc, can that be anything besides 1 or 0 ?

Comment: @SimonForsberg It cannot. This is data being sent from firmware code on physical bluetooth transmitting devices. Technically it could be changed to another byte value in the firmware code but that's not really an option right now.

Comment: @DylonJaynes you are mixing UI logic with your bussness logic. Because you are also using `binding` I guess you are using that function inside Activity. Why not use MVVM pattern? and maybe also Repository pattern

Comment: @GeorgeShalvashvili You are right. It would be better to use MVVM and Repository patterns but I didn't know much about them when I coded this application and I haven't had time to migrate. I plan on working on that in the near future though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first step, we can move all the `deviceData` properties (except `hotChargerMode`) to the top of the method and change them to booleans, as the only thing you care about is if they are 0 or not.

```
deviceData.restMode = data[28].toInt() != 0
deviceData.misbalancedMode = data[29].toInt() != 0
deviceData.leftChargedMode = data[30].toInt() != 0
deviceData.highVoltageMode = data[31].toInt() != 0
deviceData.highTempMode = data[32].toInt() != 0
deviceData.lowTempMode = data[33 + increment].toInt() != 0
```

The last `else if (increment == 1) {` can also be changed into an `else {` as `increment` can only be 1 or 0.

Then we can clearly see that we have a lot of the following pattern:

```
if (deviceData.something) {
    chargeCurrentErrorMessage = "...some message..."
    chargeCurrentMap["something"] = 1
    binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "Off"
    binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED)
    binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
} else {
    chargeCurrentMap["something"] = 0
}
```

As we can see, some `chargeCurrentMap` are directly affected by the deviceData properties, so we can move them to the top as well:

```
chargeCurrentMap["rest"] = deviceData.restMode
chargeCurrentMap["misbalanced"] = deviceData.misbalancedMode
chargeCurrentMap["leftCharged"] = deviceData.leftChargedMode
chargeCurrentMap["highVoltage"] = deviceData.highVoltageMode
chargeCurrentMap["highTemp"] = deviceData.highTempMode
chargeCurrentMap["lowTemp"] = deviceData.lowTempMode
```

Then we can see that we're basically doing the same thing if one of the values matches, and we're changing a text based on this, so we can use a `when`-statement for the text:

```
val newMessage = when {
    deviceData.restMode -> "Battery full, charger is off"
    deviceData.misbalancedMode -> "Charging is paused, battery is resolving a minor issue"
    deviceData.leftChargedMode -> "Charger is off, pack left fully charged for too long. Drive golf cart until battery reaches less than 90%"
    deviceData.highVoltageMode -> "Charger is off, battery voltage is too high"
    deviceData.highTempMode -> "Charger is off, battery temperature is too high"
    deviceData.lowTempMode -> "Charger is off, battery temperature is too low"
    else -> null
}
```

Then, if the message has a value, we use it, and set the textviewChargeCurrentStatus and questionIcon accordingly:

```
if (newMessage != null) {
    chargeCurrentErrorMessage = newMessage
    binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "Off"
    binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED)
    binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

That leaves us with this:

```
private var chargeCurrentMap = HashMap<String?, Int?>()
private lateinit var chargeCurrentErrorMessage: String

private fun processChargeModes(data: ByteArray, increment: Int = 0) {
    deviceData.restMode = data[28].toInt() != 0
    deviceData.misbalancedMode = data[29].toInt() != 0
    deviceData.leftChargedMode = data[30].toInt() != 0
    deviceData.highVoltageMode = data[31].toInt() != 0
    deviceData.highTempMode = data[32].toInt() != 0
    deviceData.lowTempMode = data[33 + increment].toInt() != 0
    chargeCurrentMap["rest"] = deviceData.restMode
    chargeCurrentMap["misbalanced"] = deviceData.misbalancedMode
    chargeCurrentMap["leftCharged"] = deviceData.leftChargedMode
    chargeCurrentMap["highVoltage"] = deviceData.highVoltageMode
    chargeCurrentMap["highTemp"] = deviceData.highTempMode
    chargeCurrentMap["lowTemp"] = deviceData.lowTempMode

    val newMessage = when {
        deviceData.restMode -> "Battery full, charger is off"
        deviceData.misbalancedMode -> "Charging is paused, battery is resolving a minor issue"
        deviceData.leftChargedMode -> "Charger is off, pack left fully charged for too long. Drive golf cart until battery reaches less than 90%"
        deviceData.highVoltageMode -> "Charger is off, battery voltage is too high"
        deviceData.highTempMode -> "Charger is off, battery temperature is too high"
        deviceData.lowTempMode -> "Charger is off, battery temperature is too low"
        else -> null
    }

    if (newMessage != null) {
        chargeCurrentErrorMessage = newMessage
        binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "Off"
        binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED)
        binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    if (increment == 0 && !chargeCurrentMap.containsValue(1)) {
        chargeCurrentErrorMessage = ""
        binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "On"
        binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(currentTextColor)
        binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.GONE
    } else {
        deviceData.hotChargerMode = data[33].toInt()

        if (deviceData.hotChargerMode == 1) {
            chargeCurrentErrorMessage = "Charger resting for a moment to let the battery cool"
            chargeCurrentMap["hotCharger"] = 1
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "Off"
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            chargeCurrentMap["hotCharger"] = 0
        }

        if (!chargeCurrentMap.containsValue(1)) {
            chargeCurrentErrorMessage = ""
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.text = "On"
            binding.textviewChargeCurrentStatus.setTextColor(currentTextColor)
            binding.questionIcon.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}
```

Which can still be shortened a bit, but I think that this is a good start.

Note that you might need to re-order the when-statement conditions, as only the first matching one will be performed.