# Android - A way to show/hide loader without writting false/true in every viewmodelScope.launch

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been writting a lot of code that looks like this

```kotlin
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
    // A fragment observes this and shows/hides a progressbar
    val loader = MutableLiveData<Boolean>() 
    
    fun fetchSomeData() = viewModelScope.launch {
        loader.postValue(true)
        // ...
        loader.postValue(false)
    }
}
```

is there a way to do it in a more clean way? if I have to do 100 requests then there will be 200 lines of loader.postValue

Comment: Note that generally on Code Review Stack Exchange, we prefer code with more context rather than less. I think you have gotten a downvote because of the `// ...` part in your code. (You can leave it as-is for now as your question has already been answered). As an example of a question with more context, see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/279291/31562

Answer (score 5):

If I interpret it correctly, you can basically wrap everything in a single method, and pass it a lambda:

```
fun launchWithPost(code: suspend () -> Unit) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        loader.postValue(true)
        code.invoke()
        loader.postValue(false)
    }
}

fun fetchSomeData() = launchWithPost {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but it wont be reusable in another screen, which will have different ViewModel

Comment: @GeorgeShalvashvili You could make it an extention method: `CoroutineScope.launchWithPost`, or have both screens implement the same interface which specifies that `viewModelScope` and `loader` should both be available, and then have it as an extension method on that interface.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I came up with:

```kotlin
fun Job.withLoader(state: MutableStateFlow<Boolean>) {
    state.tryEmit(true)
    invokeOnCompletion { state.tryEmit(false) }
}

fun Job.withLoader(state: MutableLiveData<Boolean>) {
    state.postValue(true)
    invokeOnCompletion { state.postValue(false) }
}
```

The usage:

```kotlin
fun authenticate(name: String, password: String) = viewModelScope.launch() {
    authRepo.authenticate(
        username = name,
        password = password,
    )
}.withLoader(loading)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would leave handling the `MutableLiveData<Boolean>` and launching a coroutine separate. That way it's not bound to `ViewModel` at all. The best extension to add it to is the `MutableLiveData` value itself. Also you are not doing any kind of error handling. Is it correct not to set the value back to `false` on error?

```
fun fetchSomeData() = viewModelScope.launch {
    loader.run {
        //do your magic
    }
}


suspend fun MutableLiveData<Boolean>.run(code: suspend () -> Unit) {
    postValue(true)
    try {
        code.invoke()
    } finally {
        postValue(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Good call setting false in a finally block. I'd suggest a different name than `run` because it shadows the name of standard library top-level function, impacting readability. Another possible improvement is to replace `postValue()` with `withContext(Dispatchers.Main.immediate){ value = ... }` to avoid unnecessary deferring of the UI change by a frame.